# Name of odd powered polynomial graph (Opposite of parabola(ic))

Tags: terminology, graphing-functions, education, exponentiation

I am writing an assignment and have to describe the graphs for when the powers are even and when they are odd. I described the even power graphs as being parabolic or parabolas. The only problem is, I have no idea at all as to what to call the graphs that are to odd powers (3, 5, 7, etc). So, what is the name of the shape that odd powered graphs exhibit?

Comment: I believe the term parabola is exclusively reserved for quadratic functions, that is, polynomials of degree 2.  The polynomial $1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}$ has an even power, but doesn't look much like a parabola.  I just use words like quadratic, cubic, quartic, quintic, etc.  For the general case, you could just call these graphs $n$th degree polynomials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola#Mathematical_generalizations)

> The curves $y=x^p$ for other values of $p$ are traditionally referred to as the **higher parabolas**

I believe this term could be considered old-fashioned  nowadays, but if nobody came up with a better one, I see no reason not to keep using it.

Besides, cubic parabola $y=x^3$ and semicubic parabola $y^2=x^3$ remain pretty common terms, supporting the case for calling $y=x^p$ "[some kind of] parabola".